# Bit wise modification of integers in Python

Tags: python-3.x, function

The program I'm writing manipulates integers by applying binary operations to them (e.g. `>>`, `&`, `|`). Many of the operations are applied inside functions, and to make the results of the operations persist once the function returns, I'm returning a copy of the altered variable.

Something like:

```
updated = applyOp(original, amnt)

def applyOp(original, amnt):
    return original >> amnt
```

If I didn't want to return a copy of the integer and instead wanted the changes made to `original` within the function to persist outside of the function, I suppose I could create a wrapper class of some kind. Are there other options? Perhaps ones that specifically facilitate bit wise integer manipulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, assignment to a variable changes the variable binding rather than the value at a particular memory location. In order to allow modification in the way that you are describing, I believe you will need to change stored data rather than a variable binding. Take the following example:

```
a = 1
b = a
a = 2
```

Because assignment changes the variable binding, `a` is now bound to `2`, but `b` is still bound to `1`. You really want the opposite behavior, but (to my knowledge) this behavior is not available in Python.

As you correctly say, this will require some sort of a wrapper. However, a class for this purpose isn't strictly necessary. One of the easiest ways to accomplish this is by putting your data in a list. Take this example:

```
a = [1]
b = a
a[0] = 2
```

Now, `a` and `b` still contain the same list (since no reassignment was made to either), and so `a[0] == b[0] == 2`. So one valid solution is to always pass a single-item list to the function rather than directly passing the value.

Another answer *might* be to share data between functions by making them both methods of the same class, which of course can share member variables. However, I cannot tell from your limited information if this approach is appropriate for you.

Here is an example of how this could potentially work:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._value = 0;

    def do_something(self):
        # Do something with self._value
        self._helper_function()
        # Continue using self._value

    def _helper_function(self):
        # No need to pass the value in. It is accessible at self._value
```

Again, whether or not this would work depends on exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm interested in the "same class approach". I'm trying to see how that would fix the problem though - if I made a class with a integer member variable and passed that variable into a class function, I'd still be making a copy of the reference to the member variable. That means I wouldn't be able to reassign it (same problem I'm currently facing).

Comment: @Adam I edited to add an example of how this could work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are coming from a language like C and have not familiarized yourself with the internals of Python yet.

In python, all objects are passed by reference. This means no copying is going on when you call a function. You can test this by looking at the ID (memory location) of your objects:

```
x = 0

print(id(x))

def f(y):
    print(id(y))

f(x)
```

In both cases, the ID is the same, so they are in fact the same object and not a copy.

At first this seems ridiculous, because how would changing a value work?

```
x = 1
print(id(x))
x += 2
print(id(x))
```

As you can see, the ID changed. Instead of x increasing, we got a whole new object! This is because `int` is an *immutable type*.

That means that when an operation is done on the object, it returns a new object instead of modifying itself. The opposite is a mutable type, which can modify itself.

The python `str`, `float`, `int` and `tuple` types are immutable, while the `dict`, `list` and `set` types are mutable.

However generally I would advise you to care less about the implementation details and minute performance differences, even if it's temping to worry about stuff like this. Make the code work well and be readable first and take care of possible performance issues once they actually arise.